# Batch: Checking for null value and writing a string in its place

Tags: batch-file

I have a group of text files that contain either one line of data or are blank. I need all of those files to get dumped into a single file. That part's easy enough, but I need the blank file to return a "Nodata" or similar string in the new file.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
type nul >C:\somedirectory\DataAll.txt


REM Find all files in a direcotry; for those files
for %%G in (C:\somedirectory\txt??.txt) do (
REM Find all of the text within the found files
for /f "tokens=*" %%T in ('type "C:\somedirectory\%%~nG.txt"') do (
set DataIn=%%T
    REM Check to see if the file is empty and write NoData the final variable to it if so
    if "C:\somedirectory\%%~nG.txt" LSS 1('set "/a DataIn=Nodata"')
    REM Check to see if file is not empty and write the data to the final variable 
    if "C:\somedirectory\%%~nG.txt" NEQ 0 ('set /a "DataIn=%%T"')
    REM Write DataIn to final text file
    >> "C:\somedirectory\DataAll.txt" echo !DataIn!
)   
)

endlocal
```

This duplicates the previous text file's data into the blank one. For example, if txt1 has xxx,xxx,xx; txt2 is blank; and txt3 is x,x,x the datall file will read:

> xxx,xxx,xx
>
> xxx,xxx,xx
>
> x,x,x

How do I set DataIn to another string?

Comment: What do you think is happening with this code? `if "C:\somedirectory\%%~nG.txt" LSS 1`.  This is definitely not checking the size of the file.

Comment: The `/A` option for the `SET` command is used for mathematical operations. Why are you using it?

Comment: Good to know it's not checking the size of the file. I've got something wrong then. I've played with both /a and /p. /a is the one that didn't give me any errors. I didn't realize it was mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%G in (C:\somedirectory\txt??.txt) do (
 set "DataIn=No data"
 REM Find all of the text within the found files
 for /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%T in ("C:\somedirectory\%%~nG.txt") do (
  set DataIn=%%T
 )
 REM Write DataIn to final text file
>> "C:\somedirectory\DataAll.txt" echo !DataIn!
)
```

Relying on your "either it's blank or has 1 line" info, then set the output  string `datain` to the "not found" value and overwrite it with the one data line if it's found. An empty file will not execute the `do` part of the `for %%T` loop.

Comment: Yep, it skips over the blank file. What if I need a blank line or a "filler string" for that blank line?

Comment: `Set`ting `datain` to the string "No data" at the selection of the target filename gives you the default. It will be overwritten by the `for/f...%%T` and whichever version (initial, not overwritten because empty or changed by reading line from file) is in `datain` will then be written to the output.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I missed the initial `set "DataIn.."` I have been fighting this section all day! Thank you!